# How to properly install plugins with PhpStorm and/or IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I am very confused as I have noticed it is possible to install plugins in two different ways using PhpStorm or IntelliJ.

Basically, I want to install NodeJS, MongoDB, and Socket.IO libraries, and I can do this in two ways:

1. I can enable the "NodeJS and NPM" plugin and use that to search for available packages/plugins/libraries (whatever they're called!) and install them. This method creates a new folder called "node_modules" and puts them all inside that.
2. Or search for the plugins by going to settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries > Downloads, and all of these mentioned plugins are found there for downloading and installing. Also, all of these downloaded plugins are listed under "External Libraries" and not sure where this is located on my PC. You still need to either enable the "NodeJS and NPM" plugin, or install the "node" library if you are using any node related features like the "require" function.

Which one of these is the preferred method? Does it matter? Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK 1st way is the right one. 2nd one used for code completion only (it will not be actual part of your project (cannot be served to end user in a browser) -- it is for code completion and resolution only). **P.S.** And I have no clue why you call JS libraries "plugins"

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks. I was confused with the terminology because it says they're libraries but when click to download them it calls them packages instead and I've seen the word plugin thrown around a lot. Wasn't sure..

Comment: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/

Comment: @LazyOne I tried installing jQuery and jQueryUI using NodeJS and NPM but it says that "$" is an unresolved function. Should I use method 2 for this instead?

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for the link. Will give that a read.

Comment: Check that post as well as search the blog in general -- you should find the answer (I believe so).

Comment: jQuery you can install via Bower as well. Or just download and place it in the project manually.

Comment: After reading that article it seems that you should only add libraries to node_modules if you need to use "require" in a JavaScript file. But you should use jquery as an external library just for highlighting/debugging purposes as it does not require Node for jquery to work and is not executed on the server side. Still seems confusing but thanks for the help!